# Gantt over time with summed bar

Tags: tableau-api

I'm having trouble creating the following chart in Tableau.

I have data that looks like this:

```
name    date    count
a   11/10/2012  2
a   12/10/2012  3
a   13/10/2012  2
b   12/10/2012  6
b   13/10/2012  2
b   14/10/2012  3
c   14/10/2012  2
c   15/10/2012  2
```

And I want to create a bar chart that has the sum of the count on the y axis and time on the x axis. The width of the bar should be the length of the time, like a Gantt chart. Each name has its own bar. Here is an image that shows what I am after.

[image: example image]

The bars should overlap if the times overlap.

I have tried various things in Tableau but haven't really got close.

Is this kind of chart possible in Tableau? If not in 7, will it be in 8? I have heard it makes it possible to create some more complex chart types.

A workbook with data can be found at http://community.tableausoftware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/188799-12362/Gantt%20over%20time%20with%20summed%20bar.twbx.zip

Thanks for your help,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The trick with Gantt charts in Tableau is to put a calculation on the size shelf that calculates the duration of each bar in units of days. See the example screenshot at [Tableau example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qe5Q.jpg)

You also need a continuous date field on the columns shelf to get a horizontal time axis.

In this example, I also did a few more optional things, such as, turned off aggegation under the analysis menu to get a mark per data row, rather than aggegating them, added a discrete date to the rows shelf to make each bar go on a different line (as long as each bar starts on a different date) and hid the column for that start date.